# What version of HTML is used on Struts Tags?

Tags: html, xhtml, struts2

Are the Struts2 Tags compliant to the HTML 4.01 strict standard, the HTML 4.01 transitional, XHTML 1.1 or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts2 uses the concept of [templates and themes](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html). The default template engine is [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/), and XHTML is the default theme. You can modify these settings in the [struts.properties](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/strutsproperties.html) files.